# Which runtime platforms and versions have implemented ES6 modules and import export syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, es6-modules

The syntax below:

```
import someModule from './some/path';

// DECLARE OR EXECUTE SOME STUFF

function fooBar() {
  return;
}

export const foo = 'bar';
export default fooBar;
```

I have always read in docs and tutorials that this is the **ES6 import/export syntax**.

So I've always assumed that it came around along with the ES2015 (ES6) spec, right?

But why is it not shown in the Kangax compatibility table?

I cannot find it anywhere in the table. How can I know which platforms/versions have implemented it?

https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Can I use" appears to have what you're looking for:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_statements_import

Compatibility for desktop browsers:

- Edge >= 16 (Oct 2017)
- Chrome >= 61 (Sep 2017)
- Firefox >= 60 (May 2018)
- Safari >= 10.1 (Mar 2017)
- Opera >= 47 (Aug 2017)

For mobile browsers the info is a bit more limited, but the dates are likely in the same ballpark.

Should you use ES6 imports in user code today? Probably not if your application is intended to be used by a general audience, unless you're targeting a specific runtime that is known to support it. Give it a couple more years.

What's commonly done instead is to use a bundler such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [FuseBox](https://fuse-box.org/) (I've personally had a great experience with the latter). This way you can use the import syntax in your codebase, while the end user gets a single combined .js file which handles module imports/exports in a more compatible way.